# How can I pass JSON data into a Nunjucks template?

Tags: jinja2, nunjucks

I want to use Nunjucks templates but want to pass in my own JSON data to be used on the templates.

The documentation here is pretty sparse.

https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html

Thank you.

Comment: See [Passing data to includes](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/issues/539#issuecomment-203538566) from the Nunjucks Issues

Answer (score 11):

You can use [gulp-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-data)
which allows you to pass json files to the task runner you're using to render Nunjucks.

```js
gulp.task('nunjucks', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/pages/**/*.+(html|nunjucks)')
    // Adding data to Nunjucks
    .pipe(data(function() {
      return require('./app/data.json')
    }))
    .pipe(nunjucksRender({
      path: ['app/templates']
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
});
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a webpack relevant for gulp-data? I want to pass data.json to nunjucks with Webpack.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use `dump` and `safe` filters combined:

```
<script>
  const choices = {{ yourJsonVar | dump | safe }};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Found this gem here in 2019, but thought it'll be helpful for people like me, who have searched but didn't find anything.

First, create a template part with expected arguments in a macro

```
{% macro render(secTitle, secSubtitle) %}
    <h4 class="heading">
        {{ secTitle | safe }}, {{ secSubtitle | safe }}
    </h4>
{% endmacro %}
```

Save it as `[yourname].tpl` - in this case `heading.tpl`

Then, import this block and use a function specified in macro above (`render()` in this case)

```
{% block heading %}
    {% import "components/heading.tpl" as heading with context %}
    {{ heading.render(
        secTitle='Hello there',
        secSubtitle='General Kenobi'
    ) }}
{% endblock %}
```

This will result in:

```
<h4 class="heading">
    Hello there, General Kenobi
</h4>
```

Please notice `| safe` after strings in a component - this means it'll output the string with HTML formatting (eg. `<br>` will create a new line instead of outputting `<br>` in text).

Comment: The only thing you are missing in this example is how you associate json data from somefile.js to your template macro. I think you would get more upvotes on revealing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use their async render to achieve that.

https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#render

```
$.getJSON('/path/to/file.json', function (result) {
        nunjucks.render('path/to/template/file.html', { result : result }, function (err, res) {
            // do something
        });
    });
```

Comment: This seems to just print `[object Object]` for me.

Comment: That's because you are getting an array containing the objects inside it. You need to extend the result : result to how  your JSON is constructed like result : result[0] or pass the first array item in the function's parameter.